# Access non static method from outside of class in Java (Android app)

Tags: java, android, semaphore, producer-consumer

i am doing android app in which i am doing producer consumer problem. I have following code:

```
package nu.hci.codemenao;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;

public class Resource {
    public Queue<String> semaphore = new LinkedList<String>();

    public synchronized void addString(String commands) {
        semaphore.add(commands);
        notify();
    }

    public synchronized String getString() {

        while(semaphore.isEmpty())
            try{ wait();}
            catch(InterruptedException e){}
        return semaphore.remove();
    }
}
```

How do I call `addString()` and `getString()` from other classes? I have another class that puts into the queue and another that reads out.

I tried to make semaphore queue and methods static but then I can not use `notify()` and `wait()` (got error: `non static method notify() can not be referenced from static context`).

Comment: If you follow my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33202013/913286 your design will be much simpler, you just need the right Queue.

Comment: @GilVegliach, yeh, I just have no idea how to use Blocking queue in the context of my problem

Comment: `BlockingQueue<String> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>()`; you insert strings with `q.put("asdf")` and remove them (blocking) with `q.take()`.

Comment: @GilVegliach, how to acces it from other classes, can i declare it public static? EDIT: sorry of course i can)

Comment: You can do that: having a static queue accessed from multiple classes (you don't even need the Resource class). Another approach would be to pass the queue as a parameter in the constructors of those multiple classes (i.e. the producer and the consumer class)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is meant to be a comment. I'd advise against using static in the most part of any program. Most of the time static can be avoided.

If there is only going to be one `Resource` class then yes, you could make it static and it could be accessed like this:

```
Resource.getString();
```

Or

```
Resource.addString("Hello!");
```

However, if you want to create multiple `Resource` instances then you'll need to instantiate a `Resource` object and access it from the different threads like this:

```
Resource r1 = new Resource();
r1.addString("Hello!");
String s = r1.getString();
```

Where the add and get statements can be executed in seperate Threads.

Steppers

Comment: what about notify() and wait() methods, if i declare my getString etc methods static then i get error that notify() can not be accessed from static context

Comment: Yes that's because if a method is static then everything used within that method must also be static. The notify and wait methods are not static because they are associated to a specific Resource object, which when static does not exist. Sorry, maybe a bit confusing!

Comment: You can only call other static methods within a static method. `notify()` and `wait()` are not static. [Java Object Docs!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify())